# JavaScript и wordpress

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress

Помогите сделать такую функцию на сайте. Есть картинки, на которых изображен товар для продажи. Есть форма для отправления заказа. Можно ли сделать так, что бы при нажатие на изображение, товар изображенный на этом картинки добавлялся в форму для заказа. Буду очень благодарен за помощь, с чего начать и куда двигаться. Может кто подскажет как правильно это искать

Answer (score 1):

> Для точного ответа на ваш вопрос, вам необходимо его точнее
>   сформулировать. Т.е. привести пример кода формы и элементов с которыми
>   вы работаете (в вашем случае это пример разметки товаров, например), так
>   же указать плагины, которые используются в Wordpress и участвуют в
>   формировании выдачи товаров и отправке писем (если такие
>   используются). Так как данную задачу можно реализовать очень многими
>   способами. Ниже приведу пример самого простого решения, которое не подразумевает использование плагинов wordpress.

Можно воспользоваться jquery:

**1** Берем вашу форму, допустим, она с id "order". В форме нам необходимо добавить невидимое поле input, где вы будете хранить значение (ссылку на изображение), например:

```
<form id="order">    
   ...
   <input type="hidden" name="selectedProduct"/>
   ...
</form>
```

**2** Создаем обработчик клика по картинке, допустим, картинки будут с классами "product-image". Необходимо при клике по ним брать src изображения и передавать это значение полю "selectedProduct":

```
$('.product-image').click(function(){
    $('#order input[name="selectedProduct"]').val($(this).attr('src'));
});
```

Теперь при отправке формы у вас будет параметр "selectedProduct" с url выбранного изображения. Останется его обработать и добавить в отправку по почте.

Если необходимо отображать картинку в самой форме, необходимо добавлять в форму тэг img с полученным нами изображением. Для этого в форму добавим div с классом "selected-product-image" и изменим немного наш обработчик клика:

Форма:

```
<form id="order">    
   ...
   <div class="selected-product-image"></div>
   ...
   <input type="hidden" name="selectedProduct"/>
   ...
</form>
```

Обработка клика:

```
$('.product-image').click(function(){
    var $imgSrc=$(this).attr('src');
    $('#order input[name="selectedProduct"]').val($imgSrc);
    $('#order .selected-product-image').html('<img src="'+$imgSrc+'" alt="товар"/>');
});
```